# In Azure function app on Queue Trigger I am unable to insert a record in Storage table

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I am new to Azure function app, I have a requirement where I need to have a Queue Trigger based on which I need to insert a record a Storage table.

```
     @FunctionName("echo")
     public void echo( @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { "post" }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,route="items") String in,
     @TableOutput(name = "$return", tableName = "people", partitionKey="lastName" ,rowKey = "firstName" , connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") OutputBinding<CustomerEntity> obj,
   ExecutionContext context    ) {
    context.getLogger().info( "Hello, " + in );
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyItem myItem = null;
    try {
        myItem = objectMapper.readValue(in, MyItem.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            context.getLogger().info( "Hello, " + in + " and " + myItem.getNameOfValue() + ".");
    CustomerEntity customerEntity = new CustomerEntity(myItem.getNameOfValue(), myItem.getId());
    customerEntity.setEmail("Walter@contoso.com");
    customerEntity.setPhoneNumber("425-555-0101");
    obj.setValue(customerEntity);
}
```

CustomerEntity Class
        public class CustomerEntity extends TableServiceEntity {

```
public CustomerEntity(String lastName, String firstName) {
    this.partitionKey = lastName;
    this.rowKey = firstName;
}

public CustomerEntity() { }

String email;
String phoneNumber;

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return this.phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
}
```

In This case the function is call successfully but it does not print any of the logs neither it put the data in storage tables.

I am using the local storage for this purpose.

I have tested that the application works standalone with the Table client but didnt works in function apps.

Thanks ,
Balki

So after lots of search I got the working code

```
     public class QueueTriggerJava {
/**
 * This function will be invoked when a new message is received at the specified path. The message contents are provided as input to this function.
 */
@FunctionName("QueueTriggerJava")
public void run(
    @QueueTrigger(name = "message", queueName = "enqueue", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") String message,
    @TableOutput(connection="AzureWebJobsStorage",name="table",tableName="people",partitionKey="orders",rowKey="1") OutputBinding<People> out,
    final ExecutionContext context
) throws Exception {
    context.getLogger().info("Java Queue trigger function processed a message: " + message);
    People people = new People(String.valueOf(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10, 20)));
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    People peoplew = objectMapper.readValue(message, People.class);
    people.setId(peoplew.getId());
    people.setNameOfValue(peoplew.getNameOfValue());
    out.setValue(people);
    context.getLogger().info("Java Queue trigger function processed a message: " + message);

}
```

}

I am facing the challeng that whenever I put the message on Queue it takes the same rowKey most probably bcoz of the static value of rowkey.

```
public class People{
private String PartitionKey;
private String RowKey;
private String nameOfValue;
private String id;
public People(){

}
 public People (final String rowKey){
     this.PartitionKey = "Orders";
     this.RowKey = rowKey;
 }

 /**
  * @param id the id to set
  */
 public void setId(String id) {
     this.id = id;
 }

 /**
  * @return the id
  */
 public String getId() {
     return id;
 }
 /**
  * @param nameOfValue the nameOfValue to set
  */
 public void setNameOfValue(String nameOfValue) {
     this.nameOfValue = nameOfValue;
 }

 /**
  * @return the nameOfValue
  */
 public String getNameOfValue() {
     return nameOfValue;
 }
```

}

Comment: See http trigger in your code but queue trigger is also mentioned, which one do you use?

Comment: Its my bad actually I was trying with http trigger and I am unable to get the control of storage table within the code. So after converting the data from json To object I need to persist in the storage table which I am unable to do

Comment: Hi All, I got the solution working I am posting the code this is with the queuetrigger rather than Http Trigger but should work with the http Trigger too.

Comment: Could you put your edit as an answer so that others can see clearly there's a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Now Table Binding @TableOutput is support in only for Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle of 2.0. It is not supported in 3.0, 4.0 Version. The host.json file is

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  } 
}
```

The code that works for me is

Model class is

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Order {
    private String PartitionKey;
    private String RowKey;
    public int quantity;
    public double unitPrice;
}

/*
{
"PartitionKey":"home",
"RowKey":"01",
"quantity":9,
 "unitPrice":8
 }
        */
```

The trigger function is

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import org.azure.storage.queuetrigger.to.table.model.Order;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class QueueTriggerToTableFunction {
/**
 * Azure Functions with Azure Storage Queue trigger.
 */

    @FunctionName("storage-QueueTrigger-to-table")
    public void run(
        @QueueTrigger(name = "message", queueName = "messages", connection = "StorageConnection") Order message,
        @TableOutput(name="order",tableName = "Orders",connection = "StorageConnection") OutputBinding<Order> order,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
      
        order.setValue(message);
    
    }
}
```

Actually it will take partitionKey and rowKey from OutputBinding order. So it is dynamic not static values